# Is if in an if statement a keyword?

Tags: if-statement, bnf

Is the word `if` in an `if` statement called a `keyword`? I'm aware that the PHP documentation calls it a language construct. The C# documentation doesn't list it as a `keyword`. I don't know what to call it.

Comment: Yes it's a keyword in most languages (and also in PHP and C#).

Comment: I missed something: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/#:~:text=Keywords%20are%20predefined,%20reserved%20identifiers,because%20if%20is%20a%20keyword. It is listed as a keyword.